# Error definiendo una variable php

Tags: php, html5

Tengo un problema al tratar de determinar si una variable esta indefinida con isset() pero al ejecutarlo solo me muestra el mensaje de la primera opción como puedo solucionarlo .

Agradecería su ayuda.

El programa muestra qué asignatura corresponde a la primera hora de un determinado día de la semana ingresado por teclado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Ejercicio1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="ejercicio1.php" method="post" class="formulario">
        <input type="text" name="dia" autofocus><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Aceptar">
        <?php
            $dia = (isset($_POST['dia']));
            switch($dia) {
                case "lunes":
                    echo "Desarrollo en Entorno Servidor";
                    break;
                case "martes":
                case "miércoles":
                    echo "Libre Configuración";
                    break;
                case "jueves":
                    echo "Despliegue de Aplicaciones";
                    break;
                case "viernes":
                    echo "Diseño de Interfaces Web";
                    break;
                case "sábado":
                case "domingo":
                    echo "¡Ese día no hay clase!";
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "El día introducido no es correcto.";
            }
        ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partamos de la base que *isset()* es una función booleana que sólo te determina que la variable existe y se encuentra inicializada, es decir, que no es *NULL*.
Eso lo dice claramente el [manual de referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php).
Pero eso no implica que el valor cargado sea el que quieres...

A mi entender lo que debería tener esa linea es simplemente algo como esto:

```
if(isset($_POST['dia']))
{
  $dia = $_POST['dia'];
            switch($dia) {
                case "lunes":
                    echo "Desarrollo en Entorno Servidor";
                    break;
                case "martes":
                case "miércoles":
                    echo "Libre Configuración";
                    break;
                case "jueves":
                    echo "Despliegue de Aplicaciones";
                    break;
                case "viernes":
                    echo "Diseño de Interfaces Web";
                    break;
                case "sábado":
                case "domingo":
                    echo "¡Ese día no hay clase!";
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "El día introducido no es correcto.";
            }
}
```

Obviamente, debería contener una condición de else que despliegue un mensaje de error de entrada.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió

Comment: @RandyMonteroZambrano si te sirvió dale `respuesta aceptada` para que @G'Kuan reciba sus puntos

Answer (score 1):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

La estructura `swith ... case` se puede sustituir también por otra estructura de datos, por ejemplo un array asociativo que pondría en relación `clave => valor` las diferentes opciones. De ese modo se crea un código más fácil de mantener (si en un futuro hubiera una nueva opción solamente se agregaría en el array y nada más) y menos largo, porque se evitarían todos los `case ... break`.

Aplicado a tu código sería algo muy simple:

- Un array (`$dayOptions`) que asocie los días con su respectivo valor, incluyendo un valor para `default`
- Obtener la clave que se habrá de buscar en `$dayOptions` mediante un ternario que evalúe dos cosas:

  *a*. Que el POST no esté vacío

  *b*. Que el valor del POST se encuentre en `$dayOptions`.

  Sólo si *a*  y *b* se cumplen sabremos con certeza que se podrá obtener el dato de `$dayOptions`, de lo contrario, se obtendrá el dato correspondiente a  `default`.

#### Código

**<kbd>[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/BSI40782)</kbd>**

Ahora el código. Te va a sorprender su brevedad y sencillez sobre todo a la hora de obtener el dato que se ha de mostrar en pantalla.

```
$dayOption=array
                (
                    "lunes"=>"Desarrollo en Entorno Servidor",
                    "martes"=>"Libre Configuración",
                    "miércoles"=>"Libre Configuración",
                    "jueves"=>"Despliegue de Aplicaciones",
                    "viernes"=>"Diseño de Interfaces Web",
                    "sábado"=>"¡Ese día no hay clase!",
                    "domingo"=>"¡Ese día no hay clase!",
                    "default"=>"El día introducido no es correcto."
                );  

$mDay= ( !empty($_POST['dia']) && array_key_exists($_POST['dia'],$dayOption) )  ? $_POST['dia'] : "default";
echo $dayOption[$mDay];
```

¡Eso es todo!

Hagamos algunas pruebas con varios POST simulados:

```
$_POST=array("dia"=>"lunes");
echo $dayOption[$mDay];
```

**Salida:**

```
Desarrollo en Entorno Servidor
```

---

```
$_POST=array("dia"=>"doming");
echo $dayOption[$mDay];
```

**Salida:**

```
El día introducido no es correcto.
```

---

```
$_POST=array("dia"=>"default");
echo $dayOption[$mDay];
```

**Salida:**

```
El día introducido no es correcto.
```

---

```
$_POST=array("dia"=>"miércoles");
echo $dayOption[$mDay];
```

**Salida:**

```
Libre Configuración
```

Answer (score 0):

empieza con un

```
if(isset($_POST['dia'])){$dia = $_POST['dia'];
            switch($dia) {
                case "lunes":
                    echo "Desarrollo en Entorno Servidor";
                    break;
   resto del codigo
       }
   }
```